# Collisions with other trait methods

Tags: php, traits, php-5.5

How can I deal with traits with methods of same name?

```
trait FooTrait {
  public function fooMethod() {
        return 'foo method';
  }

  public function getRow() {
        return 'foo row';
  }
}

trait TooTrait {
    public function tooMethod() {
        return 'too method';
    }

    public function getRow() {
        return 'too row';
    }
}

class Boo
{
    use FooTrait;
    use TooTrait;

    public function booMethod() {
        return $this->fooMethod();
    }
}
```

error,

> Fatal error: Trait method getRow has not been applied, because there
>   are collisions with other trait methods on Boo in...

What should I do about it?

And also, with two same method names, how can I **get** the method from `trait FooTrait`?

```
$a = new Boo;
var_dump($a->getRow()); // Fatal error: Call to undefined method Boo::getRow() in...
```

**Edit:**

```
class Boo
{
    use FooTrait, TooTrait {
        FooTrait::getRow insteadof TooTrait;
    }

    public function booMethod() {
        return $this->fooMethod();
    }
}
```

what if I want to get the method `getRow` from `TooTrait` via `Boo` as well? Is it possible?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

PHP Documentation about conflicts:

> If two Traits insert a method with the same name, a fatal error is
>   produced, if the conflict is not explicitly resolved.
>
> To resolve naming conflicts between Traits used in the same class, the
>   insteadof operator needs to be used to chose exactly one of the
>   conflicting methods.
>
> Since this only allows one to exclude methods, the as operator can be
>   used to allow the inclusion of one of the conflicting methods under
>   another name.
>
> Example #5 Conflict Resolution
>
> In this example, Talker uses the traits A and B. Since A and B have
>   conflicting methods, it defines to use the variant of smallTalk from
>   trait B, and the variant of bigTalk from trait A.
>
> The Aliased_Talker makes use of the as operator to be able to use B's
>   bigTalk implementation under an additional alias talk.

```
<?php
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }

    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }

    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}
```

So in your case it could be

```
class Boo {
    use FooTrait, TooTrait {
        FooTrait::getRow insteadof TooTrait;
    }

    public function booMethod() {
        return $this->fooMethod();
    }
}
```

(*it works even if you do separate `use`, but i think it's more clear*)

Or use the `as` to declare an alias.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! can I ask - what if I want to get the method `getRow` from `TooTrait` via `Boo` as well? Is it possible?

Comment: declare an alias. `TooTrait::getRow as getRowOfToo;` try

Comment: Also cracked it like this. In my opinion, the current behaviour is not the expected behaviour. I also expected, that an "as" is passed on to the using class.

Comment: Note that, surprisingly, you do NOT get a fatal error when a method in the class conflicts with an identically-named method in a trait that is used in that class, even though the trait's method is unreachable.

Answer (score 4):

yes this is possible you can use something like this (answer for edited content) :

```
class Boo {
    use FooTrait, TooTrait {
        FooTrait::getRow as getFooRow;
        TooTrait::getRow as getTooRow;
    }

    public function getRow(... $arguments)
    {
         return [ 'foo' => $this->getFooRow(... $arguments), 'too' => $this->getTooRow(... $arguments) ];
    }

    public function booMethod(... $arguments)
    {
        return $this->getFooRow(... $arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this tested code?

Answer (score 0):

With the accepted answer, you can cover every possible need but if your situation is simple as mine, you can just make a trait who uses your other trait which cause collasion.

```php
trait FooTrait {
  // ...

  public function fooMethod() {
        return 'foo method';
  }

  // ...
}

trait MyFooTrait {
    use FooTrait;

    public function fooMethod() {
        return 'my foo method';
    }
}

class Boo
{
    use MyFooTrait;
}
```

In my situation `FooTrait` comes from a vendor PHP package and I want to use it with enhanced methods in several classes of my own app.