# The use of traits replace the role of multiple inheritance no PHP?

Tags: php, traits

What happens if I use a class in two different traits, and both have a method with the same name but different implementations of this method?

Comment: Try to imagine all life as you know it stopping instantaneously and every molecule in your body exploding at the speed of light.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Here's a [visual reference](https://media.giphy.com/media/EldfH1VJdbrwY/giphy.gif) to go along with that

Comment: @Machavity: I was talking about, _total protonic reversal_...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collisions with other trait methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064470/collisions-with-other-trait-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

[image] (c) AbraCadaver

### Long answer

Say you have a class **Foo** that uses traits **A** and **B**:

```
class Foo {
    use A, B;
}
```

Where both traits have a method with a similar name, but different implementation (the implementation doesn't matter, really):

```
trait A {
    public function bar() {
        return true;
    }
}

trait B {
    public function bar() {
        return false;
    }
```

Traits work by extending the class horizontally. Simply put - just adding any new contents to the class. And all works fine till there's any doubling in trait methods and properties. Then you have yourself a fatal error if this conflict is not explicitly resolved.

The sweet part is, you *can* resolve this conflict by specifying which method from which trait to use:

```
class Foo {
    use A, B {
        B::bar insteadof A;
    }
}
```

You can also save the other method from oblivion by using alias for it:

```
class Foo {
    use A, B {
        B::bar insteadof A;
        A::bar as barOfA;
    }
}
```

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) has traits farely well documented, go check it out.