# Trait method __sleep has not been applied, because there are collisions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits

I am trying to trigger an event whenever an user is created but but this error pops up.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;

class NewUser
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(App\User $user)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;

    }


}
```

I have tried searching for this __sleep function but I can't find it, and I've also tired various things with using `use App\User` int the top vs in the function parameter itself.

What is the issue?

Comment: You have two `use SerializesModels;`.

Comment: This looks like its down to a typo, but should you encounter genuine conflicts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064470/collisions-with-other-trait-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the trait `SerializesModels` twice in your class definition. That causes an error, when the trait is applied a second time. `__sleep()` just happens to be the first method in the trait. [Simplified example](https://3v4l.org/tA0he)

Edit to add: Since you said you didn't find the `__sleep()` function, it's [right here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesModels.php)

Comment: Beat me to it by that much. :p

Comment: To be fair. Your comment popped up right before I pasted the link. Technically your comment was faster, but I didn't want to delete the explanation.

Comment: Actually, the reverse happened for me. Having an explanation is better anyway.